# Two Domain pointing to the same Wordpress installation

Tags: errors, domain

Hi I've got an issue with domain pointing. I am using MultiDomain plugin to point two domains to the same Wordpress installation. The website is working properly on the first domain but on the second domain there is no menu and following error:

> Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /homepages/40/d444244322/htdocs/wp-includes/post-template.php on line
>   389
>   class="">

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Adding a link for the plugin probably help someone to answer. I think should be [this](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-domains/) but I can't be sure.